# Decode JSON value from URL

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to fetch the json data from url and print it on my site. What is wrong with my coding?

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$json_string = 'https://www.unocoin.com/trade.php?all';
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($obj);
?>
```

Comment: you have to tell us what's wrong with your code. What errors are being thrown? what's the result? What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: What errors are you getting back?

Comment: The result is blank page. I need to print the values available over the url https://www.unocoin.com/trade.php?all

Comment: Try putting `var_dump($json_string)` before the `json_decode()`, that way you can confirm if the problem is with the decode or if the site is preventing you from pulling the data down.

Comment: That API seems to have some safeguards in place to prevent indiscriminate access. Perhaps you should ask them on how to correctly include it in your application.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the owner of the page is using some sort of frame/htaccess redirection to show the results.

If you do "var_dump($jsondata)" you will notice a html code that is not shown when visiting directly the website.

Check the owner's guide on how to use their API to get the results.